# filename.whl is not supported wheel on this platform RaspberryPI3

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, pip

I would like to install PyQt5-5.6-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl that I have saved to local drive. I am using:

pip 9.0.1 from python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
when I run:

```
pip3 install PyQt5-5.6-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

I get the following error:

```
PyQt5-5.6-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on
this platform.
```

I would like to know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it is because the wheel is for x86 systems and not ARM systems. I've had problems installing pyqt5 using pip on pi. I stuck with using the versions in the repositories.